# Как переопределить класс из vendor package?

Tags: php, laravel

Как переопределить класс из vendor package?
Пытался сделать так:

**App\Providers**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\BaseController;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\DataCollector\ModelsCollector;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Collector for Models.
 */
class ModelsCollectorCustom extends ModelsCollector
{

    public function collect()
    {
        ksort($this->models, SORT_NUMERIC);

        return ['data' => array_reverse($this->models), 'count' => $this->count];
    }
}


class DebugbarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register(){
        $this->app->when(BaseController::class)
            ->needs(ModelsCollector::class)
            ->give(function ($app) {
                return $app->make(ModelsCollectorCustom::class);
            });
    }
}
```

**app.php** конфиг

```
App\Providers\DebugbarServiceProvider::class,
```

но что-то новый класс не работает

**P.S.**

```
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\LaravelDebugbar;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider as BarrServiceProvider;

class DebugbarServiceProvider extends BarrServiceProvider
{
//    public function boot() {
//        parent::boot();
//        dump('butt');
//
//        $this->app->when(LaravelDebugbar::class)
//            ->needs(ModelsCollector::class)
//            ->give(function ($app) {
//                return $app->make(ModelsCollectorCustom::class);
//            });
//    }
    public function register(){
        parent::register();
        
        // $this->app->when(LaravelDebugbar::class)
        $this->app->when(BarrServiceProvider::class)
            ->needs(ModelsCollector::class)
            ->give(function ($app) {
                return $app->make(ModelsCollectorCustom::class);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Кэш очистили через artisan cache:clear, а также config:clear? Если нет, то конфигурация закэшированная в bootstrap’е не даст вам назначить новый поставщик. Также проверьте конфигурацию, публикуемую через php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider" чтобы в ней был нужный вам класс.

Comment: @ Daniel Protopopov, кэш чистил, нечего не выходит всё-равно.  `чтобы в ней был нужный вам класс` - подскажите, куда именно его нужно вписать? т.е. какой ключ? там ведь массив с ключами-значениями, конфиг уже скопирован в `app\config`, что туда нужно добавить?

Comment: Смотрите насчет авто-определения сервиса [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219976/how-to-extend-vendor-package-service-provider-in-laravel-5-5)

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, сделал как советуют (добавил в вопрос), но как теперь переопределить класс? сам провайдер `DebugbarServiceProvider` работает, а как переопределить класс?